# Measure area from autocad then send it to website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, autocad

I use autocad to measure areas like homes and property. And I have a website to create a report using the meaurement as an input. I want to know if there is a way to send the meaurement results automatically from autocad to my website? The autocad should output location name and area in m2. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD supports [.NET programming](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16459234) when you can read the area information of polygons. Then you need generic .NET programming to upload that into your website (e.g. using REST).

You may also use C++ or LISP, but it's a bit harder to connect to online.